# How to display text with two-color background?

Tags: android, andengine, libgdx, android-view

I need to create an app for android, where the 2-color text will be displayed on the 2-color background. See picture on the left. Then, the line should be moved with animation and result image should be like on the picture on the right.

I have the following questions:

1. Should I use some 2d engine to do this? Or, will it be OK to use standard views? How to do it?
2. How to draw the text like on the pictures?

[image: pic1] --------- [image: pic2]

Comment: I can tall you this, this is not easy task at all. But very good beginning could be to use some customized component such as canvas

Comment: Is there any function, which can revert the text color depending on background?

Comment: have you figured out how to implement this? i might have an answer if you didn't

Comment: @Ludevik, I have not. Will be waiting for your answer then ;)

Comment: 4 years later you're opening a bounty? I can't think of a simpler way than the below answer for doing it in the Android graphics API. With a game engine like Libgdx, it would be easy. 1. Draw white text on black background to a frame buffer object. 2. Draw mask as white on black to another frame buffer object. 3. Draw the two frame buffer object's color textures to the screen with a shader that uses the mask to invert colors.

Comment: I think it should be easy with shaders.
First, draw the complete text in white over black background. And then run invert the colors of the part you want with a mask...

Answer (score 17):

In **Android** graphics **API** i would use clip path to create clip region. 
Steps:

- fill canvas with black color:

[image: black canvas]

- draw your white text on canvas:

[image]

- create clip path and apply it to your canvas (see [Canvas.clipPath(Path)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#clipPath%28android.graphics.Path%29))
- fill canvas with white color:

[image]

- draw the same text as in step 2 in black on canvas:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can create a custom view that masks your text using a PorterDuff filter.

Here is how it could look:

```
public class MaskedText extends View {

    String sText;
    Paint p, pReplace, pMask;

    public MaskedText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // base paint for you text
        p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        p.setTextSize(40);
        p.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        p.setColor(0xFF000000);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        // replacement color you want for your the part of the text that is masked
        pReplace = new Paint(p);
        pReplace.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        pReplace.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER));

        // color of the drawing you want to mask with text
        pMask = new Paint();
        pMask.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        pMask.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        sText = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();

        // here you draw the text with the base color. In your case black
        canvas.drawText(sText, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, p);

        // then draw the shape any graphics that you want on top of it
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, 50, pMask);
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2 + 50, getHeight()/2 + 5, 20, pMask);
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2 - 45, getHeight()/2 - 10, 30, pMask);

        // finally redraw the text masking the graphics
        canvas.drawText(sText, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, pReplace);

        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

This is the result:
[Masked text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSPft.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is not complete answer I just giving suggestions.
I know one possible solution how can you do the picture on the left and the picture on the right. But The part I cant figured out is the animation. I mean if you want smooth animation between states. If you just want to swap views that is easy, just take a view fliper and that it, but I do not think that you want to achieve that...

One of the things you can do is to set background let say with 320 width and let say 0-160 white and 160-320 black. Then

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='black'>black on white</font> <font color='white'>white on black</font>"));
```

of course you will need to do precise calculation of how many letters will be black and how many white, but that is the concept

Comment: I think there is more easy solution - I need to draw the text twice - first with white color and secondly with black. But I shouldn't use standard TextViews for this.

Comment: I just suggest you one way to do it, I am sure that there are more precise solutions to do what you want to do, this was the first I came up with

Comment: Did you find some other solution ?